# CUPS: The printer is unreachable at this time

Tags: networking, printing, cups

I have the following problem: I setup my printer **EPSON stylus SX525WD** via CUPS. To do so, I:

1. Accessed the web interface at [http://localhost:631/admin](http://localhost:631/admin/)
2. Clicked on "Add printer"
3. Selected *EPSON656CC1 (Epson Stylus SX525WD) (Epson Stylus SX525WD)* at *Discovered network printers*
4. This provides me with the following address: *dnssd://EPSON656CC1%20(Epson%20Stylus%20SX525WD)._printer._tcp.local/*
5. When I finish the setup, the printer is listed under the *Printers* tab in the web interface, the status is *Idle*.

However, when I now print a page, the printer does nothing and the status changes to *The printer is unreachable at this time.*

The log file at `/var/log/cups/error_log` says the following:

```
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] time-at-processing=1630348281
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] 3 filters for job:
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] epson-escpr-wrapper (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/Epson_Stylus_SX525WD, cost 0)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] job-sheets=none,none
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] argv[0]="Epson_Stylus_SX525WD"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] argv[1]="5"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] argv[2]="sfuehr"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] argv[3]="Bestätigung in zwei Schritten"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] argv[4]="1"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] argv[5]="EPRendering=None XRXColor=BW INK=MONO SelectColor=Grayscale HPColorMode=GrayscalePrint ProcessColorModel=Mono BRMonoColor=Mono PrintoutMode=Normal.Gray BRPrintQuality=Black Collate Duplex=None ColorMode=Mono media=iso_a4_210x297mm CNIJGrayScale=1 ARCMode=CMBW ColorModel=Gray OKControl=Gray XROutputColor=PrintAsGrayscale BLW=TrueM job-uuid=urn:uuid:51397f87-5e63-3237-63fd-e969d719c5b4 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1630348279 time-at-processing=1630348281 PageSize=A4"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00005-001"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@thinkpadt490"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.3op2"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[19]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Epson_Stylus_SX525WD.ppd"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=dnssd://EPSON656CC1%20(Epson%20Stylus%20SX525WD)._printer._tcp.local/"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Epson Stylus SX525WD"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION=Tmp"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[26]="PRINTER=Epson_Stylus_SX525WD"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
I [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 206687)
I [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 206688)
I [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper (PID 206689)
I [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd (PID 206690)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused job-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Resolving \"EPSON656CC1 (Epson Stylus SX525WD)._printer._tcp.local\"...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Resolving \"EPSON656CC1 (Epson Stylus SX525WD)\", regtype=\"_printer._tcp\", domain=\"local.\"...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: epson-escpr-wrapper; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] OUTFORMAT=\"<none>\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Resolved as \"lpd://EPSON656CC1.local:515/auto\"...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] STATE: -connecting-to-device,offline-report
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Executing backend \"/usr/lib/cups/backend/lpd\"...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Looking up \"EPSON656CC1.local\"...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] PID 206687 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Epson_Stylus_SX525WD)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Failed to get find device cups-Epson_Stylus_SX525WD
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Epson_Stylus_SX525WD)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:The name org.freedesktop.ColorManager was not provided by any .service files
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Failed to get device cups-Epson_Stylus_SX525WD
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Color Manager: no profiles specified in PPD
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Color Manager: no profiles specified in PPD", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Color Manager: ICC Profile: None
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r360x360 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=841 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=0 -dcupsCompression=1 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[8.400000 8.400000 8.400024 8.399963] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[3]=\"CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[4]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[6]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[7]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[8]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[9]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[10]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@thinkpadt490\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[11]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.3op2\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[12]=\"TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[13]=\"USER=root\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[14]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[15]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[16]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[17]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[18]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[19]=\"LANG=en_US.UTF-8\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[20]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Epson_Stylus_SX525WD.ppd\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[21]=\"RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[22]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=application/pdf\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[23]=\"DEVICE_URI=dnssd://EPSON656CC1%20(Epson%20Stylus%20SX525WD)._printer._tcp.local/\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[24]=\"PRINTER_INFO=Epson Stylus SX525WD\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[25]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=Tmp\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[26]=\"PRINTER=Epson_Stylus_SX525WD\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[27]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[28]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[29]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] envp[30]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Start rendering...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Start rendering...", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Processing page 1...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Processing page 1...", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:21 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 5] Processing page 2...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Processing page 2...", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 4] Unloading...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 5] Processing page 3...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Processing page 3...", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 5] Rendering completed
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Rendering completed", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:22 +0200] [Job 5] PID 206688 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) exited with no errors.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] [Job 5] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] [Job 5] EPSON656CC1.local=192.168.0.166
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] [Job 5] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=6, addr=0x55c32cc49ad8, side_cb=0x55c32bd531d0)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] [Job 5] Copying print data.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Copying print data.", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] [Job 5] backendRunLoop(print_fd=-1, device_fd=7, snmp_fd=6, addr=0x55c32cc49ad8, use_bc=0, side_cb=0x55c32bd531d0)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:26 +0200] [Job 5] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
I [30/Aug/2021:20:31:28 +0200] Saving job.cache...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:28 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:30 +0200] [Job 5] prtGeneralCurrentLocalization type is 0, expected 2!
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:30 +0200] [Job 5] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...

... A lot of those lines ...

D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] [Job 5] PID 206689 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/epson-escpr-wrapper) exited with no errors.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] [Job 5] Connecting to EPSON656CC1.local:515 for printer auto
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] [Job 5] Connecting to printer.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "Connecting to printer.", current level=INFO
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:31 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(---J-)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] [Job 5] Set job-printer-state-message to "The printer is unreachable at this time.", current level=WARN
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Discarding unused job-progress event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Discarding unused printer-state-changed event...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Report: clients=2
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:34 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:42 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:31:42 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:31:55 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:31:55 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
I [30/Aug/2021:20:32:02 +0200] Saving job.cache...
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:02 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:13 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:32:13 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] Report: clients=2
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:32:36 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:04 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:33:04 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] Report: clients=2
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:33:37 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:10 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:34:10 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] Report: clients=2
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:34:43 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:16 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:35:16 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] cupsdAddCert: Adding certificate for PID 0
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] Report: clients=2
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:35:49 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:22 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:36:22 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:44 +0200] [Client 125] HTTP_STATE_WAITING Closing for error 32 (Broken pipe)
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:44 +0200] [Client 125] Closing connection.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:44 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs", busy="Printing jobs"
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] Report: clients=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:36:55 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:37:28 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:37:28 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] Report: clients=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:01 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:38:34 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:38:34 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] Report: clients=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] Report: jobs=4
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] Report: jobs-active=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=642
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=10232
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:07 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=12152
D [30/Aug/2021:20:39:40 +0200] [Job 5] Connection error: No route to host
W [30/Aug/2021:20:39:40 +0200] [Job 5] The printer is unreachable at this time.
```

Pinging the printer via `ping 192.168.0.166` (I got the IP address by accessing the interface of the printer itself) results in the error message *Destination Host Unreachable*.

Running `traceroute 192.168.0.166` returns *1  thinkpadt490 (192.168.0.109)  3033.085 ms !H  3033.044 ms !H  3033.027 ms !H*.

`lpstat -t` returns the following:

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: Epson_Stylus_SX525WD
device for Epson_Stylus_SX525WD: dnssd://EPSON656CC1%20(Epson%20Stylus%20SX525WD)._printer._tcp.local/
Epson_Stylus_SX525WD accepting requests since Mon 30 Aug 2021 08:31:21 PM CEST
printer Epson_Stylus_SX525WD now printing Epson_Stylus_SX525WD-5.  enabled since Mon 30 Aug 2021 08:31:21 PM CEST
        The printer is unreachable at this time.
Epson_Stylus_SX525WD-5  sfuehr          111616   Mon 30 Aug 2021 08:31:19 PM CEST
```

So at the moment I'm quite confused why I can't reach the printer when I ping it, but the CUPS web interface finds it when using the automatic setup wizard when adding a new printer as well as running `lpstat -t`. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to try next? I couldn't find anything similar in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CUPS/Troubleshooting and I don't really understand what to make of the `traceroute` results.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your printer URI starts with DNSSD which, I believe, means that it is trying to use the Bonjour protocol to talk to the printer.

So, the next thing to try would be to verify that you have Bonjour installed and working on your system.